# A method is called twice sometimes via Soap service

Tags: java, soap, wsdl

I have two project modules, let's say
1.Pasha_1
2.Pasha_2(Also Contains database call's)

a method in Pasha_1 i.e refreshSession(sessionId, validityTimePeriod) is calling a method in Pasha_2 i.e refreshSession(sessionId, ValidityTimePeriod).

The parameter's are passed in request through SOAP service.

But first let me explain my project flow.

1. refreshSession is used to refresh the session (extending the validity of the session).
2. Session details are stored in database.
3. after the session's are refreshed, we delete the Old session data from database.
4. New session details are stored in the database.

But my issue is that some calls from Pasha_1 to Pasha_2 are duplicated, Due to which First refresh call is successfully executed, but

During the duplicated refresh call, the method searches for session details in the database, "as we delete the details of session once refreshed ", it doesn't find any details and throws an exception.

Has someone seen this before? Does anyone have a hunch what might be causing
this? Or is it
normal?

- Pasha_1 code is as follows.
- public String refreshSession(Sring sessionId,Long validity){
  .................................
  final RefreshSessionRequest request = new RefreshSessionRequest();
  request.setSession(sessionId);
  request.setValidityPeriod(validityTimePeriod);
  final refreshSessionResponse response = 
  Pasha_2_soapservice.refreshSession(request);
  return response.getsessionId;
  }

  2.@WebMethod
  @WebResult(name = "refreshSessionResponse", partName = 
  "refreshSessionResponse")
  public RefreshSessionResponse refreshSession(
      @WebParam(name = "refreshSessionRequest",partName = "request")
      RefreshSessionRequest request)
      throws Exception
  ;
- Pasha_2 code is as follows.

  1. @Override
     @WebMethod(operationName = "refreshSession")
     public RefreshSessionResponse refreshSession(
     @WebParam(partName = "request", name = "refreshSessionRequest")
     RefreshSessionRequest request) throws Exception {
     final String sessionId = userSessionApi.refreshSession(request.getSession(), request.validityPeriod);
     final RefreshSessionResponse response = new RefreshSessionResponse();
     response.setSessionId(sessionId);
     return response;
     }

Comment: provide samples of your work

Comment: I have updated the description with the code.

Comment: daily 2000 to 3000 calls are made to refresh the session and are successfully refreshed, only a few around 40-50 call's get duplicated and on the second attempt to refresh with the same sessionId, exception is thrown.

Comment: @Dan, Please don't the formatting of my desc, I'm new to stack overflow